# Python: String to CamelCase

Tags: python, string

This is a question from Codewars:
Complete the method/function so that it converts dash/underscore delimited words into camel casing. The first word within the output should be capitalized only if the original word was capitalized (known as Upper Camel Case, also often referred to as Pascal case).

The input test cases are as follows:

```
test.describe("Testing function to_camel_case")
test.it("Basic tests")
test.assert_equals(to_camel_case(''), '', "An empty string was provided but not returned")
test.assert_equals(to_camel_case("the_stealth_warrior"), "theStealthWarrior", "to_camel_case('the_stealth_warrior') did not return correct value")
test.assert_equals(to_camel_case("The-Stealth-Warrior"), "TheStealthWarrior", "to_camel_case('The-Stealth-Warrior') did not return correct value")
test.assert_equals(to_camel_case("A-B-C"), "ABC", "to_camel_case('A-B-C') did not return correct value")
```

This is what I've tried so far:

```
def to_camel_case(text):
    str=text
    str=str.replace(' ','')
    for i in str:
        if ( str[i] == '-'):
            str[i]=str.replace('-','')
            str[i+1].toUpperCase()
        elif ( str[i] == '_'):
            str[i]=str.replace('-','')
            str[i+1].toUpperCase()
    return str
```

It passes the first two tests but not the main ones :

```
 test.assert_equals(to_camel_case("the_stealth_warrior"), "theStealthWarrior", "to_camel_case('the_stealth_warrior') did not return correct value")
    test.assert_equals(to_camel_case("The-Stealth-Warrior"), "TheStealthWarrior", "to_camel_case('The-Stealth-Warrior') did not return correct value")
    test.assert_equals(to_camel_case("A-B-C"), "ABC", "to_camel_case('A-B-C') did not return correct value")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is not actually the root of things, but in general it's best not to name your variable `str` which shadows the builtin `str`

Comment: You can't use `str[i]` because `i` is a `str`. And `str[i+1].toUpperCase()` won't do what you want anyways, because `str.toUpperCase` is not an in-place method. It returns a new `str`, but leaves the original untouched.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You may have a working implementation with slight errors as mentioned in your comments, but I propose that you:

- split by the delimiters
- apply a capitalization for all but the first of the tokens
- rejoin the tokens

My implementation is:

```
def to_camel_case(text):
    s = text.replace("-", " ").replace("_", " ")
    s = s.split()
    if len(text) == 0:
        return text
    return s[0] + ''.join(i.capitalize() for i in s[1:])
```

IMO it makes a bit more sense.
The output from running tests is:

```
>>> to_camel_case("the_stealth_warrior")
'theStealthWarrior'
>>> to_camel_case("The-Stealth-Warrior")
'TheStealthWarrior'
>>> to_camel_case("A-B-C")
'ABC'
```

Comment: Im getting the error `IndexError: list index out of range` in your implementation

Comment: Add a check for `if len(text) == 0:return text` before the line with `return s[0]...`

Comment: whoops, changed.

Answer (score 7):

```
from re import sub

def to_camelcase(s):
  s = sub(r"(_|-)+", " ", s).title().replace(" ", "").replace("*","")
  return ''.join([s[0].lower(), s[1:]])

print(to_camelcase('some_string_with_underscore'))
print(to_camelcase('Some string with Spaces'))
print(to_camelcase('some-string-with-dashes'))
print(to_camelcase('some string-with dashes_underscores and spaces'))
print(to_camelcase('some*string*with*asterisks'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think first of you should change the syntax a little because 'i' is a string not an integer. It should be

```
for i in str:
    if (i == '-'):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

this is my simple way

```py
def to_camel_case(text):
    #your code herdlfldfde
    s = text.replace("-", " ").replace("_", " ")
    s = s.split()
    if len(text) == 0:
     return text
   return s[0] + ' '.join(s[1:]).title().replace(" ", "")
```

Answer (score 1):

Potential solution/package that supports pascal/snake conversion to camel.

```
# pip install camelCasing
from camelCasing import camelCasing as cc

for s in ['the_stealth_warrior', 'The-Stealth-Warrior', 'A-B-C']:
    print(cc.toCamelCase(s=s, user_acronyms=None))

theStealthWarrior
theStealthWarrior
ABC
```

Comment: This should be the answer, why reinvent the wheel?  One note on this, if your string is separated by a special char, and is uppercase, we will need to lowercase the string before processing to camelCase.

Comment: Another irritating thing about this package is it capitalises the first letter in single words.  I had to implement something like this over every item in my string array:  `func = lambda lower_first_char_cc_str: cc_str[:1].lower() + cc_str[1:] if cc_str else ''`

Answer (score 1):

my  simple way:

```py
def to_camel_case(text):
    return text[0]+text.title()[1:].replace("-","").replace("_","")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def to_camel_case(text):              
    s = text.replace('_',' ').replace('-',' ').title().replace(' ','');
    return text[:1]+s[1:]
```

1)replacement needed to title
2)`del gups`
3)but in our s very first letter was eventually changed so we replaced it with the original one